# Can't download base64 as pdf file in Safari iOS with Reat JS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari, base64

I have this part of code as my function in my react project:

```
 const handleDownload = (base64String) => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64String}`;
    link.download = "manual.pdf";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };
```

it is attached to a `span` tag with an image on it. whenever I click on the `span` this function downloads a "manual.pdf" file using the `base64` string received from API.

this code works on browsers like Chrome or Firefox but it doesn't work on Safari in iOS (15.7.2)

it just shows `data:` in address bar for a moment and then nothing happens.

I tried to `createObjectUrl` by getting blob and something like this, but it didn't work. it creates weird url like this:

`blob:http://MY ADRESS HERE`. in this case it doesn't work on any browser.

is there any way to make my function compatible with Safari on iOS? I don't have mac so I don't know if the same thing applies to safari on mac or not.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

`link.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));`

instead of `link.click();` ?

Comment: no luck with this solution